# _SERVER value is not equal to what its reporting - STRANGE

Tags: php, proxy

So there is this dedicated proxy server (rtrk.com) that has a subdomain proxy set up for one of the sites that I'm responsible for.

```
The following example is how it works
Original site: example.com
Proxy site: example-px.rtrk.com
```

When the proxy site url is accessed the original site is loaded in real time. Changes made to site files on the actual site are immediately shown via the proxy URL.

I've modified the site header to check the `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` value to make sure that it ends in example.com but the behavior I'm getting is far beyond what I would consider strange, take the following code for example:

```
$test = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
echo $test . "<br />";
echo stristr($test, "exam") . "<br />";
echo $test;
exit;
```

The following output is what I expect to see:
(Accessed via proxy)

```
example-px.rtrk.com
example-px.rtrk.com
example-px.rtrk.com
```

What I actually see:

```
example-px.rtrk.com
example.com
example-px.rtrk.com
```

What the hell is going on here?
I verify that $test is set to the correct value of the proxy host.
stristr returns a completed value that is not actually even found in the original value
I then re-verify that test has not somehow changed and it has not.

This is driving me absolutely insane! How is this possible?

EDIT:

I'm able get the correct output by manually setting the test variable to the string that SERVER_NAME is reporting. Example:

```
$test = "example-px.rtrk.com";
echo $test . "<br />";
echo stristr($test, "exam") . "<br />";
echo $test;
exit;
```

This is what I get (And expect to get):

```
example-px.rtrk.com
example-px.rtrk.com
example-px.rtrk.com
```

Comment: The details of why your seeing what your seeing are beyond me. But you should never trust input, even from the *server*.

Comment: That result for the `stristr` can't be correct.  Versions?  OS?

Comment: ^^ I agree, it CANT be correct, but thats what it is... My best guess at this point is black magic. CentOS 6, brand new server PHP 5.3

Comment: This can't be right. There must be some step missing, for example you updated the wrong file while testing, or there is a delay in the deployment process. Please make absolutely sure that the code you posted gives the posted results, perhaps with some more echos and/or a timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL - It's always something stupid when I cant figure it out.

The problem is that when I access the site via the proxy, all data matching "www.example.com" is automatically converted to the proxy address on the fly before its returned to my browser.

So long story short, everything was working the way it was suppose to, just the output was being modified before it reached my browser by the proxy server.

Answer (score -1):

You are using stristr in a funny way. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) is the documentation of stristr. According to the documentation, you are searching for the String "exam", so you never would have received "example-px.rtrk.com" from the function.

Comment: No offense man, but here is the definition of stristr "Returns all of haystack starting from and including the first occurrence of needle to the end.". Which is exactly what is NOT happening here. The first 4 letters of the string I'm searching are exam and therefore the whole string (haystack) should be returned. Furethermore, if I change the fist line of the script to $test = "example-px.rtrk.com" then everything works as expected.

Comment: I have no further idea, from what I know, then even if it works correctly then it shouldn't work like that, but I don't have the experience with the method to know anymore. Sorry I couldn't answer your question.